# mmap and hash table extension issue in glibc

Tags: malloc, virtual, hashtable, glibc, mmap

In an approach to detect the heap corruption I am trying to implement a hash table to keep some information about the malloced memory. This is being done inside glibc itself. When we malloc(), we put the information like address and size in the hash table and when we free(), we deallocate the corresponding hash table entry, again in glibc's free() itself.

To allocate memory for the hash table i have mmap'd some memory (refrained from using malloc for this, as the chances of process induced heap corruption can corrupt my hash table also).
The issue is that there is no limit to the number of mallocs that a process can ask for, this requires my hash table to be extensible. Since my hash table works on array indices, memory used for hash table need to be contiguous so that using an index we can easily reach the bucket or record. Now, when hash table uses all the memory, i need to do a 'mmap' again in such a way that this memory starts where the previous ended. man page of mmap says that we can provide an address to mmap, that will act as a hint to kernel to map virtual memory at that address. To the hash table, it will look like a contguouis chunk of memory. I would like to ask for you suggestions how reliable is this approach and what are the potential pitfalls using this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is Linux, you can use [`mremap`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mremap.2.html).

If you write your hash table to be based on offsets and not absolute pointers, you can pass the `MREMAP_MAYMOVE` flag and never have to worry about allocation failures.  (Well, until you exhaust your virtual memory, anyway.)

Comment: Thanks a lot 'Employed Russian' and 'Nemo' for the answers. I'll explore mremap(). Looks like if mmap is to malloc() then mremap is to realloc(), something i was needing desperately.

Answer (score 1):

> how reliable is this approach

`MAP_FIXED` is very reliable: *IF* the memory you are asking for is available, the kernel will give it to you.

> what are the potential pitfalls

The obvious one: something else may have gotten `mmap`ed into the region you want to extend into, and you lose.

If you are doing this for 64-bit process, you can `mmap` e.g. 1TB of memory as your initial hash table allocation. So long as you don't actually access it, this `mmap` is effectively free (of cost), assuming you are doing `MA_ANON` mapping.

BTW, I hope you realize that you are re-inventing a bicycle here, as many existing solutions (such as tcmalloc and jemalloc) will already provide debugging facilities that are likely to be better that whatever you concoct yourself.